# Multiple protocols

Tags: iphone, objective-c, protocols

I'm declaring that my app delegate conforms to the protocols

`<UIApplicationDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>`

in the app delegate header file (i.e. the app delegate interface).

The compiler tells me at numerous places in my code that:

`warning: type 'id <UIApplicationDelegate>' does not conform to the 'SKPaymentTransactionObserver' protocol`

What's up?

Comment: Have you declared that your delegate conforms to the two protocols in both the class declaration and the variable declaration (or however you access the variable)?

Comment: @Bavarious: Only in the app delegate interface.

Comment: Post the code where you add the transaction observer.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably doing something like `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]]`. Since `-[UIApplication delegate]` is declared as returning `id<UIApplicationDelegate>`, the compiler has no way of knowing that the object returned will implement the SKPaymentTransactionObserver protocol. Try assigning the delegate to a variable that's statically typed as your delegate class and pass *that* to the method you're trying to call and the compiler should be happy.

Comment: @Bavarious, @Chuck: Adding a cast with the variable declaration seems to fix this, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your ApplicationDelegate seems to be missing some of the required delegates, for example:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Check what delegate methods `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` requires, and add them to your AppDelegate.m

Also, check over the [SKPaymentTransactionObserver Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @WrightCS: Thanks for your post. I can replace SKPayment... with any other protocol and still have the same problem. It's not this.